# How to match Openlayers source and layers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

Opanlayers current version has `layer` and `source` objects to view vector or tile images.

**Layer Types**: Image, Tile and Vector

**Source Types:** ImageWMS, TileWMS, Geojson, OSM, Raster, Vector, …

So how can I decide which `source` Works with which `layer`? I could not found in [openlayers documents](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/index.html) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of source accepted is shown in the documentation for the layer type.  It is correct for Image, Vector and VectorTile.  Where subclasses are listed in the documentation for the source types they are usually used instead of the base class.  The documentation confusingly shows the base class Tile as the source type for Tile layers.  Subclasses of that include VectorTile which isn't appropriate as it is only used by VectorTile layers and Tile layers only use subclasses of TileImage or (rarely) TileDebug or UFTGrid.  OSM is a subclass of XYZ.  There is no GeoJSON source type in OpenLayers 5, it is just one of the formats used by Vector sources.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html uses subclasses of https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileImage-TileImage.html or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileDebug-TileDebug.html or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_UTFGrid-UTFGrid.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Image-ImageLayer.html uses subclasses of 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Image-ImageSource.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html uses https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_VectorTile-VectorTileLayer.html uses https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_VectorTile-VectorTile.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, but documentation may useful if layer page(https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html) contains which sources would be used.

Comment: It says https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Tile-TileSource.html which has subclasses TileDebug, UrlTile and UTFGrid.  UrlTile in turn has subclasses TileImage and VectorTile, but VectorTile is used only by VectorTile layers.